# how to make dc.js pie chart display data properly?

Tags: dc.js

I have this fiddle, in which I'm trying to have a dc.js pie chart display 5 "regions" from my data set:   https://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/yv3nnred/6/
Here is the data set:

```
var data = [
        {date: "2015-03-25T12:10:00", resolver: "Group 1",  escalation_pct: 20, bubble: 5, region: "Americas", x: 1},
        {date: "2015-03-25T12:15:00", resolver: "Group 2",  escalation_pct: 10,  bubble: 5, region: "AMEA",  x: 1},
        {date: "2015-03-25T12:25:00", resolver: "Group 3",  escalation_pct: 50, bubble: 10, region: "Nordics", x: 1},
        {date: "2015-03-25T12:40:00", resolver: "Group 4",  escalation_pct: 30,  bubble: 1, region: "Americas", x: 1},
        {date: "2015-03-25T12:35:00", resolver: "Group 5",  escalation_pct: 5, bubble: 10, region: "Australia", x: 1},
        {date: "2015-03-25T12:45:00", resolver: "Group 6",  escalation_pct: 13,  bubble: 1, region: "UK&I", x: 1}
    ];
```

For some reason, the pie chart does not properly display the region names.
It also has one of the slices as bright orange, while I'm not specifying any specific colors.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Update - I got the pie chart to display the region names, but, for some reason, the regain named UK&I is not being display, but there is a bright orange "Other" slice in its place. How can I make UK&I region display instead of "Other"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `.slicesCap(4)`, which means (I believe) that it will display 4 slices plus an "Other" slice. If you change this to `.slicesCap(5)` or just remove it, it will start displaying your UK&I slice.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why UK&I slice is such a bright color, as oppose to all other?

Comment: My guess is it is just the default scale. You can use any scale you want though: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.colorMixin+colors